# Checking if a date is present within a dataframe, else appending it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `dftickets` which has 47 columns.

My goal is to check if there are missing dates within, and to append those missing dates at the end of the dataframe.
I am using one of the columns which has timestamps.
The path I took was to convert them into a date (%Y-%m-%d) and use the `not in` operator to check missing date against a `daterange`. ( Note : some rows have duplicated date values)

Here is the code :

```
    # First, I convert the timestamps present in dftickets['created_at'] into '%Y-%m-%d' strings.
    dftickets.insert(0, 'Data',dftickets['created_at'].apply(
    lambda x:pd.Timestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))

    #Then, I use the newly created 'Data' column as Index.
    df = dftickets.set_index('Data')

    #Now I create the dateRange which will be used to compare. 
    dateRange = pd.date_range('2021-08-01', '2021-08-31').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    #And I compare both dateframes for missing values, if the values are missing, the date should 
    be appended, followed by columns with 0s. 
    for i in idx:
        if i not in dftickets['Data']:
            df.append([i] + ([0] * 47))
 
    print(dftickets)
```

Sadly once printed, no rows have been added. yet if I `print (i)` instead of appending,  the missing date that are being return seem to be right.

If anyone has an idea why, it would be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame.append() returns a new object. you might solve by assigning like so:

```
for i in idx:
    if i not in dftickets['Data']:
        df = df.append([i] + ([0] * 47))
```

here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)
outdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])
for x in df['A']:
    if x not in df['B']:
        outdf = outdf.append({'A': [x]}, ignore_index=True)
print(outdf)  


    A   B   C   D
0  13  16   1   0
1  13  12   3  18
2   9   4  16   1
3   2   8  16  16
4  17   2   4   6
5   9   4   2   0
6  12  10  16   9
7  13   6  11   0
8   6   4  17  17
9  18  18   4  17
      A
0  [13]
1  [13]
2  [17]
3  [12]
4  [13]
5  [18]
```